# Is the restriction of a function to its set of continuity points continuous? i.e. is $h|_{\mathcal C(h)}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Let $h: S \to S'$ be a function between topological spaces $(S, \tau)$ and $(S', \tau')$.

Let $\mathcal C(h)$ denote the continuity points of $h$.

Is then the restriction $h|_{\mathcal C(h)} : \mathcal C(h) \to S'$ a continuous function? [That is, with respect to the subspace topology $(\mathcal C(h), \tau_{\mathcal C(h)})$.]

I think the answer is yes. Here is my proof (attempt). Perhaps someone could check it.

**Proof:** If $\mathcal C(h) = \emptyset$, then $h|_{\mathcal C(h)}$ is the empty function to $S'$ and trivially continuous.

Now let $\mathcal C(h) \neq \emptyset$ and $x \in \mathcal C(h)$. Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $h(x)$. Since $x$ is a continuity point of $h$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $h(U) \subseteq V$. Then $U_0 := U \cap \mathcal C(h) \in \tau_{\mathcal C(h)}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in the subspace topology $\tau_{\mathcal C(h)}$. Furthermore $h|_{\mathcal C(h)}(U_0) = h(U) \setminus h\big(\mathcal C(h)^c\big) \subseteq h(U) \subseteq V$.

Thus, for any neighborhood $V$ of $h|_{\mathcal C(h)}$, we can find a neighborhood $U_0 \in \tau_{\mathcal C(h)}$ of $x$ such that $h(U_0) \subseteq V$. Hence, $h|_{\mathcal C(h)}$ is continuous. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to directly note the trivial inclusion $h\restriction_{\mathcal{C}(h)}[U_0] \subseteq h[U]$, the intermediate equality is not needed.

Or note:

If $x$ is a point of continuity of $h$, then it remains so in the restriction of $h$ to *any* subspace that contains $x$. So all points of $\mathcal{C}(h)$ are points of continity of $h\restriction_{\mathcal{C}(h)}$. So it is continuous on that subspace.

The proof of the first fact goes just as yours for the specific $\mathcal{C}(h)$:

Given $V \ni h(x)$ pick open $U \ni x$ that $h[U] \subseteq V$. But then $(h\restriction_A)[U \cap A]=h[A \cap U] \subseteq h[U] \subseteq V$ so $U \cap A \ni x$ witnesses the continuity at $x$ of $h\restriction_A$.